# Ionic framework with java rest backend

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm from a java background and i'm relatively new in building hybrid apps.
Thought of giving ionic a shot. I know angularjs to some extent.

Is it possible to create a hybrid mobile application using the ionic framework with a java restful backend for example - Spring Rest MVC or Jersey.

I'm really confused because most people refrain from using the above architecture, and say ionic is meant to work with MEAN stack.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Yes!

ionic is just a front-end framework. It uses AngularJS its JavaScript Framework and Cordova to bridge native functions. Just like AngularJS, ionic works with all RESTful APIs. For example, if you build a RESTful API with Spring Rest MVC or Jersey, you can easily access this API with $http service in AngularJS.

Here is a quick example: http://10minbasics.com/ionic-http-get-json/